# Echo cmd overwrites gpg file

Tags: linux, encryption, gpg

I use

```
gpg -e file
```

to encrypt file, which leaves me with a `file.gpg` file.

- I `cat` the contents and its encrypted. (`cat file.gpg`).
- Then to test it, I do this: `echo 'this is a test' > file.gpg`

This completely overwrites all encryption in the file with that string.
Why? Is there a way to make the `gpg` file not overwritable?

---

Update:

I just tested the encrypted file to see if I could overwrite it with the `echo` cmd, and it was overwritten. So, why encrypt a file with `gpg` if with a simple `echo` cmd I can overwrite it?? I tried the `chmod u-w file.gpg`, it still did not protect the file from being overwritten. Is there some other parameter in gpg that I'm not plugging in? Authentication is just my user name in `gpg`, no passphrase. I don't want the `gpg` file to be overwritten.

Comment: What do you intend to test with your `echo`? The encrypted file is just a file like any other. Truncating it and writing new data into it is allowed if the file's permission allows the current user to do so.

Comment: `chmod u-w file.gpg`

Comment: What is your intention with encrypting the file? An encrypted file is still just a file. Removing the write permissions on it would make it not over-writable (unless you're root). Removing write permissions on the _directory_ that holds the file would make the file un-deletable (unless you're root). It's the same as with any other file. What encryption _does_ is that it protects the contents from being _read_ by someone that does not have the password or key.  Please clarify the question with your intention and expectation.

Comment: If you mean command in the title, please write *command*, not *cmd*. (You can edit it)

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you would want to echo to a file with the `>` operator, since this completely overwrites it, but if you want to set a file to read-only, you should take away the write permissions.

In this case it's 
`chmod -w file.gpg`.

If you want to change the encrypted file, you should append to/change the original file and then reencrypt it.